# Неправильная отрисовка элементов CListCtrl

Tags: c++, mfc

У меня есть класс `CListCtrlEx`, который переопределён от обычного `CListCtrl`. Этот список имеет стиль `LVS_REPORT`, `LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED` и `LVS_EX_GRIDLINES`. Я прикрутил возможность смены шрифта для этого списка. Она вроде и работает, но есть одно но - если я меняю шрифт и перед этим не делаю скроллинг списка, то тогда все элементы списка перерисовываются правильно, но если я сначала сделаю скроллинг, а затем сменю шрифт, то получится, что элементы списка "съедут" чуть ниже своего положения в сетке списка, т. е. это будет выглядеть как текст перечёркнутый линиями сетки.

Код замены шрифта:

```
LRESULT CListCtrlEx::OnSetFont(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM)
{
  LRESULT res = Default();

  CRect rc;
  GetWindowRect(&rc);

  WINDOWPOS wp;
  wp.hwnd  = m_hWnd;
  wp.cx    = rc.Width();
  wp.cy    = rc.Height();
  wp.flags = SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_NOZORDER;
  SendMessage(WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED, 0, (LPARAM)&wp);

  return res;
}

void CListCtrlEx::MeasureItem(LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT lpMeasureItemStruct)
{
  HDC hDC = ::GetDC(NULL);
  CFont* pFont = GetFont();
  HFONT hFontOld = (HFONT)SelectObject(hDC, pFont->GetSafeHandle());
  CRect rect;

  DrawText(hDC, _T(" "), 1, rect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CALCRECT);
  lpMeasureItemStruct->itemHeight = rect.bottom - rect.top;
  SelectObject(hDC, hFontOld);
  ::ReleaseDC(NULL, hDC);
}
```

Ну и скриншот того, как выглядит это безобразие:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]